# What does 'computer murk' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across this term in Black Mirror S03E06 00:12:01. And I haven't found any explanation about it on Internet. The context is here:

> "So you were in Tech Crime?"
>
> "Digital Forensics. **Computer murk.**"
>
> "What happened, you get bored of it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is either spelled correctly as "murk" or it is misspelled and supposed to be "merc".

---

**MURK** (from [Merriam Webster ELL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/murk))

> *noun* : darkness or fog that is hard to see through; also : dark or dirty water

That idea of dark and dirty could apply here. "Computer murk" would then mean dark and dirty secrets held on a computer. This makes sense because the next line lists things that definitely count as dark and dirty:

> "You've seen what people tuck away on these. Schemes and kill lists, kiddy porn."

---

**MERC** short for **Mercenary** (from [Merriam Webster ELL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mercenary))

> *adjective* : caring only about making money

If I heard the show without reading the script's spelling as "murk" then I would probably assume they meant "computer mercenary" and believe it was a made up title in this world for someone who gets paid to hack computers.

But the rest of the conversation doesn't really help this fit in. A mercenary is someone who gets hired and paid for one task and they change who they work for based on who is willing to pay more.  So they don't talk about money in the next lines, and by saying:

> "So you were in Tech Crime?" "Digital Forensics."

It sounds more like a real full time job, not freelance mercenary work. It's still a possibility though because the script's spelling of "murk" that I found could have been fan-written and not the official script.